# In Phaser, is there a way to clear screen or clear game stage/world?

Tags: html, screen, phaser-framework, stage

I'm looking for a simple and quick way to clear the entire Phaser screen, like how in HTML5 canvas you can erase everything by resetting the width of the canvas to itself. I couldn't find any such method with a search - only graphics.clear(), but that doesn't hit other stuff like text objects. Is there such a way to clear screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are methods to destroy specific elements - `obj.kill()` and `obj.destroy()` - but it is possible to delete all elements by calling `game.world.removeAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

@FabiánRodríguez replied, but you can also make a array or object literal with the objects you'd like to remove, so iterate and remove each. That is when you want to group objects.

```
var layout = {
    rect: new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)
};

for(var i in layout) {
    layout[i].kill();
    layout[i].remove();
}
```